# Plot Plugin draws only part of data

Tags: jenkins, plot, jenkins-plugins

I am using [Plot Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plot/) to plot the graphs in Jenkins using `.csv` file. 
The `.csv` file contains 3 rows. /charts , /buttons and aggregated.

When the build is completed only aggregated results are plotted, not the rest two. How can I plot the rest of the rows?

Here's `.csv` content:

```
"Type","Name","# requests","# failures","Median response time","Average response time","Min response time","Max response time","Average Content Size","Requests/s","Requests Failed/s","50%","66%","75%","80%","90%","95%","98%","99%","99.9%","99.99%","99.999","100%"
"GET","/charts.html",23,0,3,3,2,4,19561,2.10,0.00,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
"GET","/index.html",27,0,4,4,2,15,31333,2.46,0.00,4,5,5,5,6,6,15,15,15,15,15,15
"None","Aggregated",50,0,3,3,2,15,25917,4.56,0.00,3,4,4,5,5,6,15,15,15,15,15,15
```

Comment: Could you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least provide any more details (like .csv content)?

Comment: "Type","Name","# requests","# failures","Median response time","Average response time","Min response time","Max response time","Average Content Size","Requests/s","Requests Failed/s","50%","66%","75%","80%","90%","95%","98%","99%","99.9%","99.99%","99.999","100%"
"GET","/charts.html",23,0,3,3,2,4,19561,2.10,0.00,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4
"GET","/index.html",27,0,4,4,2,15,31333,2.46,0.00,4,5,5,5,6,6,15,15,15,15,15,15
"None","Aggregated",50,0,3,3,2,15,25917,4.56,0.00,3,4,4,5,5,6,15,15,15,15,15,15

This is the csv content

Comment: @Tupteq do you have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there a known bug with Plot plugin,that only 1st row of CSV is plotted. You can see that by clicking Help ('?') icon.
[image: Known Bug]